# DV lottery (Green Card) application without child photo

Tags: usa, greencard, children

I've been divorced and remarried. I have a son from my previous marriage who lives with his mom, and two kids from the current one.

I'm thinking of applying for DV lottery (green card). The application requires that you include info about all your biological children with their photos.

I haven't seen my son for about 7 years now. I had issues with my ex-wife and she wouldn't let me meet my son. Obviously, I don't have my child's photo. It's nearly impossible to get his photo.

My question is: **how can I apply for DV lottery without having to include my son's photo? Is there a way that I can include his information (first name, last name, date of birth, etc.) but no photo?** I will be including all required information about my current wife, my two children who are living with me right now, but no photo of my son who is not living with me.

There are plenty of info about requirements for the photograph on DV lottery official website, but I couldn't find anything regarding to my situation.

Comment: The applications are not open right now. Make sure you're applying at the right place: https://dvprogram.state.gov/

Comment: @littleadv I know it's not open right now. I just want to research the issue with the child photo till it opens.

Comment: I believe the photo is required, looking at the DOS guidance it doesn't seem to matter whether the child lives with you or intends to come with you. Sorry.

Comment: I have the same problem. My son lives with my ex and I have no way of taking a photo of him.
Now I don't know what to do. Should I use an older photo? Or should I not include him at all... will that discualify me? What choice do I have?